# django 1.6 app tests.py to tests subdirectory

Tags: django, django-testing, django-1.6

with django 1.6, I have a django app with tests.py file

```
app
- tests.py
```

in this file I tested some management functions

```
from management.commands.getevents import some_function
```

when I try change the tests.py to a tests directory with differents tests files

```
app
- tests
-- __init__.py
-- test_models.py
-- test_views.py
-- test_managements.py
```

and I try running the test

```
python manage.py test
```

get this error

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: events.tests.test_managements
...
ImportError: No module named management.commands...
```

with the directory of test files, why django don't see the management module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly import `management` from `app`:

```
from app.management.commands.getevents import some_function
```

---

Just to prove my words with a working example, check [how custom management command is imported](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/ce442892362c00bfd1c7f4e6facb9ce3f47c8a10/compressor/tests/test_offline.py#L14) in [`django-compressor`](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tests:

```
from compressor.management.commands.compress import Command as CompressCommand
```